# How to apply VaadinIcons as marker symbols in Charts for Vaadin Flow?

Tags: java, vaadin10, vaadin-charts

I have a **Vaadin Charts Flow 6** line chart and would like to define some of the **VaadinIcons** as Marker Symbols.

How can i achieve this?

**MarkerSymbol** is an interface that is implemented as

- **MarkerSymbolEnum** for providing predefined markers such as eg. circle, square, diamond etc.
- **MarkerSymbolUrl** for providing the URL to an image that shall be used as a marker

```
AtomicInteger xValue = new AtomicInteger(0);
List<Double> yValues = new Random( ).doubles(10, -10, 10).boxed( ).collect(Collectors.toList( ));        
List<DataSeriesItem> items = yValues.stream( )
                             .map(yValue -> new DataSeriesItem(xValue.getAndIncrement( ), yValue))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList( )); 

/* Instead of MarkerSymbolEnum or MarkerSymbolUrl, retrieve a VaadinIcon*/
items.forEach(item -> item.getMarker( ).setSymbol(MarkerSymbolEnum.DIAMOND));
items.forEach(item -> item.getMarker( ).setSymbol(new MarkerSymbolUrl("foo/bar.png")));
// new Icon(VaadinIcon.CHEVRON_UP);

DataSeries series = new DataSeries("example");
series.setData(items);

Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.LINE);
chart.getConfiguration( ).addSeries(series);
```

I didn't see an opportunity to retrieve the URL of a **VaadinIcon** or directly setting it.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might dynamically construct a URL to a VaadinIcon resource as follows:

```
String loc = "https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-icons/blob/master/assets/png/"
String url = loc + VaadinIcon.CHEVRON_UP.name().toLowerCase().replace('_', '-');
items.forEach(item -> item.getMarker( ).setSymbol(new MarkerSymbolUrl(url)));
```

Vaadin also publishes [svg](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-icons/tree/master/assets/svg) VaadinIcon assets on GitHub. Alternatively, you might prefer pointing to a local directory path.

The logic used to create the url comes from [Icon](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-icons-flow/blob/master/vaadin-icons-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/icon/Icon.java) wrapper constructor `public Icon(VaadinIcon icon)`.

Vaadin doesn't currently (as of July 2019) seem to allow direct use of VaadinIcons as Marker symbols.

For reference, I've included some details of classes Marker and Icon.

**CLASS MARKER DETAILS**

Class [Marker](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-charts-flow/blob/master/addon/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/charts/model/Marker.java) (extends abstract class [AbstractConfigurationObject](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-charts-flow/blob/master/addon/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/charts/model/AbstractConfigurationObject.java)) has member [MarkerSymbol](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-charts-flow/blob/master/addon/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/charts/model/MarkerSymbol.java) which simply implements interface [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Class [MarkerSymbolUrl](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-charts-flow/blob/master/addon/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/charts/model/MarkerSymbolUrl.java) implements interface MarkerSymbol and seems to represent a simple getter/setter wrapper class around String url.

Class [MarkerSymbolEnum](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-charts-flow/blob/master/addon/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/charts/model/MarkerSymbolEnum.java) only implements a static list of enum values, so not relevant.

**CLASS ICON DETAILS**

Class [Icon](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-icons-flow/blob/master/vaadin-icons-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/icon/Icon.java) wrapper constructor `public Icon(VaadinIcon icon)` calls constructor `public Icon(String collection, String icon)` with the [VaadinIcon](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-icons-flow/tree/master/vaadin-icons-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/icon), which uses Icon superclass [Component](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/455661e3bb94f88411ad45c06623fac0eec48839/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/Component.java) functionality to call inherited member function [Element](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/455661e3bb94f88411ad45c06623fac0eec48839/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/dom/Element.java).[setAttribute(...)](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/455661e3bb94f88411ad45c06623fac0eec48839/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/dom/Element.java#L249), which stores the calculated VaadinIcon attribute string (I believe this eventually gets written out in the div tag):

```
public Icon(VaadinIcon icon) {
    this(ICON_COLLECTION_NAME, icon.name().toLowerCase().replace('_', '-'));
}

public Icon(String collection, String icon) {
    // iron-icon's icon-attribute uses the format "collection:name",
    // e.g. icon="vaadin:arrow-down"
    getElement().setAttribute(ICON_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, collection + ':' + icon);
}
```

Element extends abstract class [Node](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/455661e3bb94f88411ad45c06623fac0eec48839/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/dom/Node.java), which implements interface Serializable.

**NEXT STEPS**

Ultimately, this seems to indicate classes Marker/MarkerSymbol and Icon don't share a common superclass (other than Object), so no interoperability.

For a deeper dive, I'd look at how the various Vaadin components render the UI using the generated markup, but for now it seems using MarkerSymbolUrl and a dynamically calculated URL from the VaadinIcon represents the only straightforward workaround.

Comment: I am using Vaadin 10 and [Charts for Vaadin Flow](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-charts).
In Vaadin < 12 the DataSeriesItem, Marker, etc. is defined in the Charts code.

Comment: @SignorMacchina Thank you; I've updated my answer with a way to dynamically determine a URL to a VaadinIcon, given it's enum. With this you might set the Marker URL.